# Disable carrier "features" on IOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone

My IPhone 4 has some carrier features I would like to disable:

When ever I miss a call this thing opens and I have to close it. If I do not close it(say for ex. a missed call at night) the screen will stay on with this thing till I close it. It will often even drain the whole battery.

I'm using IOS 7 on a jailbroken(I did this hoping I would find a solution there) iPhone.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Most carrier features will need to be turned off (on) by the carrier on their end.  Not in a phone menu.

Comment: What about a hack from cydia or something? Also, what are the official name of this thing?

Comment: My carrier has something similar - you can switch it off from their web site

Answer (score 1):

Yes like previous comments suggest all carrier settings are generally toggled on or off from the carriers systems and not locally in iOS. Try searching Cydia for something specific for your carrier, however your best bet is to talk with them.

Source: work for a telco

Comment: I found a menu from the carrier in the phone settings menu and I was able to disable this annoyance from there.